# Please assist: complex standings query

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I'm developing a website for a poker club and they'd like to show the standings of their players. Players play in tournaments, and a predetermined amount of points are awarded for each placing. The club would then like to show a table of players ordered by accumulated points.

The club enters this data in a CMS, and there are four database tables. The create statement for these tables is (some fields removed for clarity):

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
);

CREATE TABLE `players_tournaments` (
  `player_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tournament_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY `player_id` (`player_id`),
  KEY `tournament_id` (`tournament_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tournaments` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `tournaments_placings` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tournament_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `player_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `placing_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tournament_id` (`tournament_id`),
  KEY `player_id` (`player_id`),
  KEY `placing_id` (`placing_id`)
);

ALTER TABLE `players_tournaments`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `players_tournaments_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`) REFERENCES `players` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `players_tournaments_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`tournament_id`) REFERENCES `tournaments` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `tournaments_placings`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tournaments_placings_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`tournament_id`) REFERENCES `tournaments` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tournaments_placings_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`) REFERENCES `players` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tournaments_placings_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`placing_id`) REFERENCES `placings` (`placing`);
```

Hopefully it's self-explanatory as to how it links up with the table naming structure, but the foreign key information is in there too.

There's also a fifth table, `placings`, which has two columns: `placing_id` which is just a `PRIMARY KEY` column; and `points` which stores how many points should be awarded for that placing.

**Question:** What would my query look like in order to pull the cumulative points of all players over the course of all tournaments, based on the points structure defined in my `placings` table?

I've seen various solutions for things like a soccer league table, but that has the points system within the query (i.e. 3 points for a win, 1 point for a draw, 0 points for a loss) whereas my poker league example has a lot more variance as it's not a case of won, lost, drawn.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems you have a flaw, a player can only take part once in Single tournament? If so, there should be primary key or unique key on player_id + tournament_id (then players_tournaments is no required)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to join `tournaments_placings` to `placings`, in order to get the points associated with all the finishes.

You're looking for total points for each player -- so you need to `group by player_id` and `sum(points)`:

```
select 
  player_id, sum(points)
from 
  tournaments_placings
inner join 
  placings
  using(placing_id)
group by 
  player_id;
```

If you also want to get the player info (not just the id), you can then join to `players`.